# Proving $T$ is a topology

Tags: general-topology

I want to show that $T$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$, where $T$ is the family of subsets $U$ of $\mathbb{R}$ with the property that for every $x\in U$ there exists $\epsilon>0$ such that $(x−\epsilon,x]\subseteq U$.

I can prove the first two topology axioms but I can't manage to show that $T$ is closed under arbitrary union.

My attempt: Suppose $U_i\in T$ for all $i\in I$ where $I$ is some indexing set. Then for all $i$ there exists $\epsilon_i$ such that for every $x\in U_i$ we have $(x−\epsilon_i,x]\subseteq U_i$. I need to find an $\epsilon$ such that for every $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ we have $(x−\epsilon,x]\subseteq \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$.

Comment: Maybe I'm misunderstanding, but shouldn't $\epsilon$ depend on $x$?

Otherwise, if $\epsilon$ is the same for all $x \in U,$ then could we "stretch" the interval to $- \infty$?

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari. Yes of course. $\epsilon$ depepends on $x$. OP: Every $x\in \bigcup_{i\in I} U_i$ is in at least one $U_i\,.$ In particular there exists an $\varepsilon>0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon,x]\subseteq U_i\,.$ Done. No?

Comment: @BrianBritosSimmari Gah! Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you're familiar with the Sorgenfrey line,  or lower-limit topology on $\Bbb R$, then the upper-limit topology is indeed a topology homeomorphic to it, by $$x\overset{h}\to -x.$$

Answer (score 0):

If $x \in \bigcup U_i$ then $x \in U_{i_0}$ for some $i_0$. Then some $(x - \epsilon , x] \subseteq U_{i_0} \subset \bigcup U_i$.